# How Do I specify a level to select on using Jquery :Contains

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select my containers where they contain a certain text, and then hide them accordingly.

However, it seems to select the sub elements too, rather than the master element.

This results in parts of my container dissapearing.

```
$("#SearchText").on("keyup", function () { 
    var text = $("#SearchText").val(); 

    $(".myList :contains(" + text + ")").show();
    $(".myList :not(:contains(" + text + "))").hide();
});
```

html:

```
<div class="myList">
  <div class="container"> <!-- Wanting to select here -->
    <div> <!-- currently selecting here -->
      word
    </div>
   <div>  <!-- currently selecting here -->
      say
   </div>

   <div>  <!-- currently selecting here -->
     hello
   </div>
 </div>
```

Attached Jfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/661p4q0j/1/

Comment: Can you give some more explanation? Its not clear, actually. what do you mean by sub elements?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thanks. Answer has been provided below, but i have improved my question to explain the issue better for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your selector more specific. In this case, to select only the `.container` element which contains the given text, and not any element contained within your `.myList` element:

```
$(".myList .container:contains(...)")
$(".myList .container:not(...)")
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/661p4q0j/2/).

Comment: I thought i had tried this before asking. Works great. thanks :)